# What is the meaning of sub-constant error?

Tags: calculus, algorithms, approximation, machine-learning

The error is defined as $E \geq \frac{1}{2ab(1+ab)}$, where $a$ and $b$ are both positive . The claim is: if we fix the value $a$, then to get a sub-constant error $E$, we must ensure that $b>\frac{1}{a}$.
Here, how to understand this claim, i.e. what is the meaning of 'sub-constant'?

Comment: Generally, "subconstant" means simply $o(1)$, or going to zero for high input values.

Comment: @Laertes   Thanks a lot. By the way, in the above question, which input value is $o(1)$ with regard to ?

Comment: Not sure. At a guess, I would say $b$, since in this case we are holding $a$ constant, but it can actually be with regard to multiple values (though more rarely); see \href {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables}{this page}. Essentially that would just mean that $E=o(1)$ for large $a$, $b$.